# Method equivalent of <%= expression %> in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Total noob question here, but not finding the answer via search.

What is the method equivalant of <%= expression %>?

I'm looking to replace this:

```
<%
 foreach (var intem in IE) {
%>
  <%= Ajax.ActionLink(item,...) %>
<% } %>
```

with:

```
<%
 foreach (var intem in IE) {
    SomeOutputCall(Ajax.ActionLink(item,...));
} 
%>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess good old `Response.Write` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Write(Ajax.ActionLink(item,...));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was response Response.Write("...") in asp, and it looks to the be he same in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the equivalent of the following:

```
<%
 foreach (var intem in IE) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Ajax.ActionLink(item,...));
} 
%>
```

or you could just use "Response.Write" like SLaks answer to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`<%=var%>` was and is simply shorthand for `Response.Write(var)`. Under the hood they're equivalent.